# Removed files from Git Commit

Tags: git, github

I have a few commited files in my GIT branch which I don't want to push it to my repository. How do I unstage them and remove the files from my branch.

I always get this file:
    "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt"

In my commit included, I don't understand how to remove this from my git commit now.

when I do a diff between branches I get the following:

```
git diff feature_mentoring_connections_v2 --name-only
"C:\\nppdf32Log\\debuglog.txt"
app/controllers/mentoring_models_controller.rb
app/helpers/mentoring_models_helper.rb
app/models/object_permission.rb
app/models/program_observer.rb
```

Now I need to remove "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" from my branch.

This is the solution:

```
git rm "C:\\nppdf32Log\\debuglog.txt"
git commit -m "Remove Files"
```

Comment: They have [an article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) on github about this.

Comment: If you don't care that the file is in the history, simply `git rm path/to/file`

Comment: if the files are commited, you'll have to revert your commit and do it again

Comment: Also see `man gitignore`

Comment: I tried doing git rm "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" But it doesn't remove the file anyways.

Comment: How do you get this file? Since you are on linux, there cannot be a windows file path. Or is this the **file** name?

Comment: I deleted my answer because based on your last comment on it, I actually don't think it will help you. You say "It's always generated somehow when I push my branch", but that strongly suggests the file exists on the remote server somewhere, and my answer was about what to do when the file only exists in your local commits.

Answer (score 1):

For already checked in files:

You will have to revert earlier commit. So when you submit, there will be 2 items in your list, first commit and second revert commit. Don't worry. Net effect of those 2 will be zero.

For other files which you don't want be part of repo, untrack them.

Comment: I always get this file: "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt"

In my commit included, I don't understand how to remove this from my git commit now. This is not part of my git repository. I am using linux and don't understand how a windows pattern file has come in here.

Comment: If you know your commits are wrong (shouldn't be pushed), and they haven't been pushed anywhere yet, why would you suggest pushing them anyway?